# Azure Webjob for Application insides issues even when disabled

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, appinsights

I recently discovered that there are error logs created every 10 mins with the following content. I can't figure out why and where they come from.
AppInisghts is deactivated for the webapp...

```
New Log File(2022/04/17/17/918a59-5808.applicationLog.csv) has been created
date,level,applicationName,instanceId,eventTickCount,eventId,pid,tid,message,activityId
2022-04-17T17:08:35,Information,boxplanner,918a59,637858121159061901,0,5808,56,Automatically redeploying web job.,
2022-04-17T17:08:36,Information,boxplanner,918a59,637858121163988746,0,5808,56,Checking NuGet for latest agent.,
2022-04-17T17:08:36,Verbose,boxplanner,918a59,637858121167270466,0,5808,-1,"System.InvalidOperationException: An error occurred while loading packages from 'https://packages.nuget.org/api/v2': The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.CallProcessAuthentication(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at NuGet.RequestHelper.GetResponse()
   at NuGet.HttpClient.GetResponse()
   at NuGet.RedirectedHttpClient.GetResponseUri(HttpClient client)
   at NuGet.RedirectedHttpClient.EnsureClient()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at NuGet.MemoryCache.GetOrAdd[T](Object cacheKey, Func`1 factory, TimeSpan expiration, Boolean absoluteExpiration)
   at NuGet.RedirectedHttpClient.get_CachedClient()
   at NuGet.RedirectedHttpClient.get_Uri()
   at NuGet.DataServicePackageRepository.get_Context()
   at NuGet.DataServicePackageRepository.FindPackagesById(String packageId)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at NuGet.DataServicePackageRepository.FindPackagesById(String packageId)
   at NuGet.PackageRepositoryExtensions.FindPackagesById(IPackageRepository repository, String packageId)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.ExtensionManager.Models.AgentModel.GetLatestAgentFromNuGet()
   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.ExtensionManager.Models.AgentModel.get_LatestNugetVersion()
   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.ExtensionManager.Models.AgentModel.DeployWebJob(String trigger, String nugetVersion)",
```

Answer (score 0):

> AppInsights is deactivated for the web app.

The possibility of getting the **telemetry** information ***after deactivating*** the **Application Insights** from the **Web App**.

- Maybe in your Application, you may **hardcode** the **configuration of Application Insights** in the **Web APP**.
- Make sure if you use custom telemetry in your application, it must contain the Application Insights configuration.

To Avoid getting the telemetry information from a web app you can try to remove the hardcoded Application Insights configuration

Refer [here](https://stackify.com/remove-application-insights/) to **remove application insights** in multiple ways.